# Do AWS Centos 6.9 and 6.10 AMIs support NVMe and ENA driver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos, amazon-ami, packer, centos-6.9

Do Centos 6.9 and 6.10 support NVMe ?  We want to create AMI of Centos 6.10 with ENA and NVMe drivers. Can it be done using packer?